# iPadOs 13.2 Beta NavigationController Crash

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, ios13, rootviewcontroller, ipados

We have a live iPad application written in XCode 6.4 which runs fine on iPadOS 12, 13.1, 13.1.2 but crashes on iPadOS 13.2 Beta.

I have created a skeleton version of the application which does nothing except attempt to show a viewController via a navigationController.

This is the code:-

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
   _window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];

    UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
    viewController.view = view;
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    [_window makeKeyAndVisible];
    _window.rootViewController = navigationController;

    return YES;
}
```

The crash happens when the rootViewController is set on the UIWindow on line 11. If lines 10 and 11 are reversed the crash happens on makeKeyAndVisible.

Thanks for any help,

```
Stack trace:-
OS Version:          iPhone OS 13.2 (17B5059g)
Release Type:        Beta
Baseband Version:    n/a
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1a6921ab8 0x1a67ef000 + 1256120
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1a663b028 0x1a6635000 + 24616
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1a681119c 0x1a67ef000 + 139676
3   QuartzCore                      0x1ad55fdc8 0x1ad401000 + 1437128
4   QuartzCore                      0x1ad55fcf8 0x1ad401000 + 1436920
5   QuartzCore                      0x1ad55f7cc 0x1ad401000 + 1435596
6   UIKitCore                       0x1aae88ff8 0x1a9fbe000 + 15511544
7   UIKitCore                       0x1aae54b60 0x1a9fbe000 + 15297376
8   UIKitCore                       0x1aae8b0e4 0x1a9fbe000 + 15519972
9   UIKitCore                       0x1aae8bd98 0x1a9fbe000 + 15523224
10  CoreFoundation                  0x1a68f364c 0x1a67ef000 + 1066572
11  CoreFoundation                  0x1a67f1300 0x1a67ef000 + 8960
12  UIKitCore                       0x1aae8ae34 0x1a9fbe000 + 15519284
13  UIKitCore                       0x1aae890e0 0x1a9fbe000 + 15511776
14  UIKitCore                       0x1aa098a70 0x1a9fbe000 + 895600
15  UIKitCore                       0x1aaea6634 0x1a9fbe000 + 15631924
16  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1a6636a4c 0x1a6635000 + 6732
17  QuartzCore                      0x1ad5552b0 0x1ad401000 + 1393328
18  QuartzCore                      0x1ad5555b8 0x1ad401000 + 1394104
19  UIKitCore                       0x1aae91f94 0x1a9fbe000 + 15548308
20  UIKitCore                       0x1aae98ad8 0x1a9fbe000 + 15575768
21  UIKitCore                       0x1aa31ab9c 0x1a9fbe000 + 3525532
22  UIKitCore                       0x1aa31bb58 0x1a9fbe000 + 3529560
23  UIKitCore                       0x1aa31b8c0 0x1a9fbe000 + 3528896
24  UIKitCore                       0x1aa3248c4 0x1a9fbe000 + 3565764
25  UIKitCore                       0x1aa3c3bf8 0x1a9fbe000 + 4217848
26  UIKitCore                       0x1aa3217dc 0x1a9fbe000 + 3553244
27  UIKitCore                       0x1aae9d054 0x1a9fbe000 + 15593556
28  UIKitCore                       0x1aae90bb8 0x1a9fbe000 + 15543224
29  UIKitCore                       0x1aae90a9c 0x1a9fbe000 + 15542940
30  UIKitCore                       0x1aae9fae0 0x1a9fbe000 + 15604448
31  UIKitCore                       0x1aaa33234 0x1a9fbe000 + 10965556
32  UIKitCore                       0x1aaa3260c 0x1a9fbe000 + 10962444
33  UIKitCore                       0x1aaa335a8 0x1a9fbe000 + 10966440
34  UIKitCore                       0x1aaa4478c 0x1a9fbe000 + 11036556
35  BasicNav                        0x1009ded14 -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 27924 (AppDelegate.m:30)
37  UIKitCore                       0x1aa9f3008 0x1a9fbe000 + 10702856
38  UIKitCore                       0x1aa9f89e0 0x1a9fbe000 + 10725856
39  UIKitCore                       0x1aa1983cc 0x1a9fbe000 + 1942476
```

Update: The same code crashes in XCode 7 and XCode 8. Runs OK in 10 (targetting iOS 10). Wondering if this will be fixed by Apple or we will need to port our code to a more recent XCode.

Comment: What is the exception message?  What happens if you use `self.window` instead of `_window`?

Comment: I have added the symbolicated crash. Using self.window makes no difference. This code also runs fine if built using XCode 11. I have tried using a xib file referenced in the info.plist to create the window automatically; the window is created but the same crash occurs, again only crashing on 13.2

Comment: Ok. I didn't realise you were actually still using Xcode 6.4. Don't do that.